# Postgres query to find all dependent tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find all objects (tables, views, ... etc) that have a dependency on a specific table.
What is a query I could write in postgres to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to query the catalog for that. Probably pg_depend:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html

Incase you ever need it, don't miss the convenience type converter that lets you turn table oids and text into relnames like so:

```
select 'pg_statistics'::regclass; -- 'pg_statistics'
select 2619::regclass;            -- 'pg_statistics' too, on my install

# select refclassid::regclass from pg_depend where classid = 'pg_class'::regclass group by refclassid;
  refclassid  
--------------
 pg_namespace
 pg_type
 pg_class
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I go about getting the object id for my class/table, is there a convenience method for that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and as you can see from the docs it can point to any number of things: another relationship, a type, etc. You'd need to join or left join the stuff accordingly to extract the gory details.